# Rollback decorator for std::streambuf for backtracking in a parser library

Tags: c++, c++14, istream, c++17, streambuf

I'm trying to implement a general parser library for purely educational purposes. The parsers are supposed to operate on arbitrary `std::istream`s. So far I've been able to get it to work for all `LL(1)` languages by using `istream::unget` to rollback the `std::istream` in case the lookahead doesn't fit.

But now I have trouble implementing the rollback for an alternative operator with backtracking for arbitrary length lookaheads. My first idea was to inherit from `std::istream` and to override `istream::get` to store read characters into a temporary buffer in order to put them back with `istream::putback` in case of a parsing failure  so that I can pass the original `std::istream` to the second parser. But unfortunately `istream::get` is not a virtual method, so that doesn't work.

It seems I have to create a custom `std::streambuf` decorating arbitrary other `std::streambuf`s with the rollback logic - even if they don't support any kind of putback themselves - but I'm unsure how to accomplish that and if that is even possible at all.

Does someone have an idea?

---

#### Edit

Since Sam Varshavchik wrote in the comments that this is the right approach, I tried to implement such a `std::streambuf` as follows:

```
class streambuf_rollback_decorator : public std::streambuf {
private:
    std::streambuf* _buffer;
    std::vector<char_type> _readChars; // to store read characters
    std::vector<char_type> _rollbackBuffer; // move read characters here in case
                                            // there is a rollback that cannot
                                            // be fully put back into the
                                            // underlying streambuf
                                            //
                                            // Chars are stored in reverse
                                            // order so that back can be
                                            // used to retrieve the next char

public:
    streambuf_rollback_decorator(std::streambuf* buffer)
        : _buffer{buffer} {
    }

    // notify the streambuf the rollback is not needed so it
    // so it can clear the saved characters
    void submitReads() {
        _readChars.clear();
    }

    void rollback() {
        std::move(_readChars.rbegin(), _readChars.rend(), std::back_inserter(_rollbackBuffer));
        _readChars.clear();
    }

private:
    int_type underflow() override {
        if (!_rollbackBuffer.empty()) {
            // if there are characters in the rollback buffer take one from there
            auto c = traits_type::to_int_type(_rollbackBuffer.back());
            _readChars.push_back(c);
            _rollbackBuffer.pop_back();
            return c;
        } else {
            // otherwise return a character from the underlying streambuf
            char_type c;
            auto num_chars = _buffer->sgetn(&c, 1);
            if (num_chars == 0) {
                return traits_type::eof();
            } else {
                _readChars.emplace_back(c);
                return traits_type::to_int_type(c);
            }
        }
    }

    int_type uflow() override {
        return underflow();
    }

    int_type pbackfail(int_type ch) override {
        char_type c;
        if (ch == traits_type::eof() && !_readChars.empty()) {
            c = _readChars.back();
        } else if (ch != traits_type::eof()) {
            c = traits_type::to_char_type(ch);
        } else {
            return traits_type::eof();
        }

        if (!_readChars.empty()) {
            _readChars.pop_back();
        }

        if (_rollbackBuffer.empty()) {
            // first try to put the char back into the underlying streambuf
            auto succ = _buffer->sputbackc(c);

            if (succ == traits_type::eof()) {
                // if the char couldn't be put back into the underlying
                // streambuf, emplace it into the _rollbackBuffer
                _rollbackBuffer.emplace_back(c);
            }
        } else {
            // if there are already characters in the rollback buffer the char
            // needs to be emplaced there
            _rollbackBuffer.emplace_back(c);
        }

        return traits_type::to_int_type(c);
    }

    std::streamsize showmanyc() override {
        return _rollbackBuffer.empty() ? 0 : _rollbackBuffer.size();
    }
};
```

Additionally I created an `std::istream` decorator that uses this `std::streambuf`:

```
class rollback_istream_decorator : public std::istream {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<streambuf_rollback_decorator> _rollback_streambuf;
public:
    rollback_istream_decorator(std::istream& s)
        : std::istream{s.rdbuf()},
            _rollback_streambuf{std::make_unique<streambuf_rollback_decorator>(s.rdbuf())} {
        this->rdbuf(_rollback_streambuf.get());
    }

    rollback_istream_decorator(std::streambuf* buf)
        : std::istream{buf},
          _rollback_streambuf{std::make_unique<streambuf_rollback_decorator>(buf)} {
        this->rdbuf(_rollback_streambuf.get());
    }

    rollback_istream_decorator& operator=(rollback_istream_decorator const&) = delete;
    rollback_istream_decorator(rollback_istream_decorator const&) = delete;
    rollback_istream_decorator& operator=(rollback_istream_decorator&&) = default;
    rollback_istream_decorator(rollback_istream_decorator&&) = default;
    ~rollback_istream_decorator() = default;

    void submitReads() {
        _rollback_streambuf->submitReads();
    }

    void rollback() {
        _rollback_streambuf->rollback();
    }
};
```

It seems to work correctly for unformatted input, but unfortunately formatted input is broken, e.g. the following simple program doesn't behave the same as with a regular `std::cin`.

```
int main() {
    rollback_istream_decorator istream{std::cin};

    std::string rem;
    istream >> rem;
    std::cout << rem << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

In this example one has to press Enter twice for inputs of even length in order to see any output and it only prints every second character. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Usually, you don't operate on character streams directly. You build a tokenizer on top of this, and then use this tokenizer as a higher level construct. This way you can have a larger buffer where you can putback an arbitrary amount of tokens.

Comment: You're reading from the stream directly, not from iterators? Why..?

Comment: @ildjarn As far as I can tell `std::istream_iterator` does not support rolling back at all, since it cannot be decremented. I don't see how they would be of any help here.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Isn't tokenization dependent on the actual grammar? I'd like the library to work for any user defined grammar, so I'd need a way to infer the different kind of tokens from the user defined grammar in order to create the tokenizer. This seems like it would need a lot of expression template magic, if it even is possible.

Comment: @Corristo : It wouldn't help directly, but it would be a layer of abstraction that _could_ help. See e.g. [Boost.Spirit's multi-pass iterator](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/support/multi_pass.html).

Comment: @ildjarn I'll have a look into that. Thanks.

Comment: You're on the right track. You need to subclass `std::streambuf`, and implement your rollback within your subclass. Implementing `std::streambuf`'s interface is not trivial, and will require some bit of work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I added an implementation to the original question, unfortunately something is wrong. Do you have experience with implementing streambuf and can help me with that?

Comment: I haven't looked closely, but this is nowhere near what I was suggesting. This subclasses a `std::istream`, ending up instantiating another `std::istream` that shares the same `std::streambuf` as `std::cin`. That's already a dubious approach. I didn't say anything about subclassing `std::istream`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The subclass of `std::istream` is in addition to the subclass of `std::streambuf` to facilitate the extra features of my own streambuf, similar to how `std::ifstream` is a subclass of `std::istream` to make use of the additional features (e.g. `open` and `close`) of `std::filebuf`. Moreover the constructor taking a `std::istream&` of my own istream is only for convenience so I don't have to write `rollback_istream_decorator s{std::cin.rdbuf()};` but can write `rollback_istream_decorator s{std::cin};` instead.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with my subclass of `std::istream`, the same problem arises when replacing the buffer of `std::cin` by the decorated version via `streambuf_rollback_decorator buf{std::cin.rdbuf()}; std::cin.rdbuf(&buf);` and then using `std::cin` instead of `istream` in the example above.